# Rspec Controller Test No Route Matches Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, routes, rake

Rspec is not recognising my controller routes. I am using Versionist gem to version my API and I am using a path version (so `/v1/` to version my API as shown below.).

```
constraints :subdomain => "api" do
  api_version(:module => "V1", :path => {:value => "v1"}, :defaults => {:format => :json}, :default => true) do
  match '/orders' => 'orders#index', :via => :get
```

The route in rake routes is shown as:
`GET /v1/orders(.:format) V1/orders#index {:subdomain=>"api", :format=>:json}`

My controller is located in `app/controller/v1/orders_controller.rb`.

For the rspec test, I have a `orders_controller_spec.rb`, I have:

```
require 'spec_helper'

module V1
  describe OrdersController do
    describe "GET #index" do
      it "throws an error on incorrect params" do
        get :index
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The error I get is:

```
 1) V1::OrdersApiController GET #index throws an error on incorrect param
     Failure/Error: get :index
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"v1/orders"}
```

What is wrong here? How come no route matches `v1/orders`? In `rake routes`, I see the route right there as shown above: `GET /v1/orders(.:format) V1/orders#index {:subdomain=>"api", :format=>:json}`. It says `GET /v1/orders`. Where is the problem here?

Comment: it's because of the subdomain I guess, try: `request.stub(:subdomains).and_return(['api']); request.host = "api.example"`

Comment: That did not work. Do I need to change `api.example` to something? What would that be? I'm running on localhost (using api.lvh.me when actually doing requests). I tried setting it to http://api.lvh.me but that also did not work.

Comment: @apneadiving I added `api.example.com` to my `/etc/hosts` and added your two lines in a `before(:each)` block and it still does not work. Any ideas how to get it working?